# add method is not adding a drop-down option in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a dropdown named gameType in which i am adding a value dynamically .

```
function addGameType(){

    var gameType=document.getElementById('GameType');

    var all=document.createElement("option");
    all.text="ALL";
    all.value="ALL";
    gameType.add(all,gameType[0]);
    gameType.options[0].selected=true;

}
```

the code is correctly adding new value in dropdown in chrome and firefox but not adding it in IE browser .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the function get called correctly in IE? Does it work if, instead of that approach, you use `gameType.add( new Option('ALL', 'All', false, true) );`? Or `gameType.insertBefore(all, gameType.firstChild)`? Are there any errors reported in the developer console? Is it really Internet Explorer  (which version), or Edge?

Comment: Hi , i was getting type mismatch error in IE console. i have tried gameType.add( new Option('ALL', 'All', false, true) ); and it is wroking perfectly . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For `option` element you should use `label` attribute instead of `text`. For other DOMElements you should try `textContent`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: No, the `<option>` element-node ([`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)) has a `text` property (although it does apparently have a `label` property too).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery? If so, you could try the following:

```
$('#GameType').append($('<option>', {
    value: 'All',
    text: 'All'
}));
```

Then you can select the option using:

```
$("#GameType").val("All");
```

Comment: i had tried the above solution but it was not populating the value in dropdown .

Comment: gameType.add( new Option('ALL', 'All', false, true) ); this has solved my problem . thanks Dawcars for your effort.